# Microcontroller stops responding after accessing registers of uninitialized peripheral

Tags: controller, embedded, pwm

I am working on ARM cortex M3 processor. After accessing MCPWM register controller stops responding in which no interrupts will work.
Intentionally I have not initialise MCPWM.
So i wanted to know, where actually code flow(Program counter) goes, reason of controller hang.

Comment: Cortex-M3 defines only the MCU core and not the implemented peripherals. The peripheral implementation is _always_ vendor specific, so you need to specify the actual MCU part number, because the core has nothing to do with it.  Also of course, show the code that generates this result.  Otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: My advice is don't try to work on embedded systems without a debugger.  Then you halt the processor in the debugger and can see directly where the PC is.  If it "hangs" it is probably in a default interrupt or exception handler, and normally the defaults are indefinite loops.

Comment: Another possibility is that you have configured the MPU to restrict access to the MCPWM.  Nonetheless your question clearly lacks sufficient detail and information to answer - voting to close for the time-being as it stands.,

Comment: Does MCPWM == Motor Control Pulse Width Modulation register? If so, I don't think ARM cortex-m3 provides any such system register. Most probably, such a register is provided by the chip vendor. From the internet, it seems ESP32 has such a register.

Comment: One will have to look at the datasheet, to find out as to what happens on uninitialized access to such a register. My educated guess tells me it might lead to a fault of some type. Since your observation is that the controller goes to a hang with interrupts not working, it might have led to a Hard or Usage fault.

Comment: Most chip vendors, have a busy loop when a Hard/Usage fault occurs. If you have a debugger available, you can try attaching it and see what the contents of below registers are when the issue arises. 1: Configruable Fault Status Register (For Usage Fault) 2: Hard Fault Status Register (HFSR)

Comment: If you have access to the complete source code or symbol, you can also try connecting the device via gdb and try to break where the source code is halting. It will probably be in a fault handler.

Comment: Guys, sorry for late reply... I got debugger and i have observed when issue occurred. Found that, MCPWM (Motor Control PWM) LIM2 interrupt register not getting cleared in ISR (even i did)
- I am using Cortex M3 based LPC17xx micro-controller
- When this issue occurred, other Timer interrupt is working but while (1) loop does not execute as controller stuck in Handler mode. xPSR register was contained ID-46 i,.e. MCPWM ISR. operation mode was Handler mode. No other faults occurred.
- This code works 10000+ times for MCPWM logic and this issue occurred randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply..

I am using LPC17xx series.

```
{    
LPC_SC->PCONP |= 0x00020000;             
LPC_PINCON->PINSEL3 |= (0x01<<18)| 
(0x01<<24);
LPC_MCPWM->TC2 = 0;
LPC_MCPWM->LIM2 = 2048;
LPC_MCPWM->MAT2 = 1024;

  LPC_MCPWM->CON_SET = 1 << 17;
   LPC_MCPWM->CON_SET = 1 << 18;
   LPC_MCPWM->CON_CLR = 1 << 19;

   LPC_MCPWM->DT &= ~(0x3FF << 20);
  
   LPC_MCPWM->DT |= (channelSetup- 
   >channelDeadtimeValue & 0x3FF) << 20;


   LPC_MCPWM->CON_CLR = 1 << 20;
   NVIC_EnableIRQ(MCPWM_IRQn);

   LPC_MCPWM->INTEN_SET = 0x01 << 8;
}
```

This is part of the code which is used to initialize MCPWM
But intentionally this code is commented and controller hang after executing
below code which is used to stop MCPWM

```
{
    regVal |= (1 << 16);

    LPC_MCPWM->CON_CLR = regVal;

  }
```

I will buy debugger to monitor fault registers.

Comment: Please add these details to the question instead of adding them as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
void MCPWM_IRQHandler(void)
{
  uint32_t TempRegVal;
  TempRegVal = LPC_MCPWM->INTF;  //PC was pointing here after code stuck
  if(TempRegVal & ILIM1)
  {                                                                                               
  }                                                                                                              
  if(TempRegVal & ILIM2)
  { 
  }
  LPC_MCPWM->INTF_CLR = TempRegVal; //Interrupt flag cleared
  return;
}
```

Any Idea why interrupt flag not getting cleared or is there any other best way to clear this flag?

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35250613)